# Visualization of river- animation via code

Tags: animation, visualization

I am trying to visualize a river flow- basically, should be able to visualize river current direction and speed based on an user-defined external parameter. This is required to demonstrate vectors in two dimensions- given education needs, animation quality can be minimal- 'tolerable enough'.

I tried a simplistic approach by a blue background with lines indicating currents- comes out very weak and below my low standards!!

Can someone point out a good example/ approach for achieving the same? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an image filter that looks like water.  Look at [Jerry's image filters](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html).  Specifically look at the the [caustic filter](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/CausticsFilter.html).  You could animate it moving from one end of the river to the other end.  You can also experiment with varying the time parameter.  Since it's open source, you can translate it to other languages.

Here are some [links to 3d visualizations](http://www.vterrain.org/Water/).